# date function help

Tags: php, datetime, date, datepicker

I have this invoice with todays date:

I want to display the expiration date (30 days later), is there a function that allows this?

or is it something simple like adding a +30 somewhere?

Help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help you.

```
$thirtydaysadd = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("y"));
echo "That day will be ".date("m/d/y", $thirtydaysadd); 

mktime() is used to create new time stamp.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = date();

$future = date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_string('30 days'));
```

is the procedural way to do it. There's also an OOP version [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) as well.

Comment: `echo $future` seems rather obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `date()` and `strtotime()`.

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days'));
```

For more information on specifying date formats, see the [manual page for date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: hey thnx! but look: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: @NORM, must be somewhere else, or a mistake with copy+pasting it. It works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` is probably your best bet.

> echo strtotime("+30 days"), "\n";

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

When you face such problems, PHP online documentation is very useful.

Just for to http://php.net/keyword (for example, http://php.net/date) and documentation page for that keyword will be displayed. You could see [Date/Time functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) in the left sidebar which has the link to function [date_add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php)